# Separating web domain from email domain - sound security strategy?

Tags: wordpress, security

A friend's website was recently hacked. (An outsourced project manager wasn't diligent in applying Wordpress security updates.)

An unfortunate effect of the hacking is that ISP's are now flagging emails sent from his company as spam.

To prevent the same thing happening in the future (emails getting recognized as spam as a result of a hacking), he is considering separating out the domain for his company's presence from the domain used in his company's email addresses.

Does this seem like a sound strategy?

Or is this overkill - and as long as appropriate plug-ins (e.g., https://ithemes.com/security/) and periodic updates are applied, he shouldn't worry about similar problems in the future?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that won't be the domain name itself that is being blocked, it is more likely the IP address.

It can be a good idea to have a mail server on a different IP address to the website, but if the problem was caused by the site sending emails (you don't specify what the hack was) then the only solution is to change the IP address of the mail server or wait for the server mail reputation to be restored.

If the server is on shared hosting this is likely affecting a number of customers and the web host may step in if they receive enough complaints.

You can check the email reputation of the IP address at https://talosintelligence.com/